# Why is the Dogfish Head 120 minute IPA so expensive?

Tags: ipa, price

I enjoy a good Dogfish Head 120 minute IPA, it is the only beer I can casually drink at home and it actually gives me a buzz, but I am curious as to why does it have such a high price point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there are three main reasons.

1) **Direct production costs**. Dogfish declares adding hops for two hours, and this has a cost you need to pay (more hops, more time)

2) **Alcohol content**. Taxes *may* depend on ABV (for minimum rate of excise duty on beer in the EU, see [here](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:31992L0084&from=IT)). The higher is the ABV, the higher is the tax.

3) **Marketing**. The beer is a very special one, and it is easier for Dogfish to find consumers willing to pay more for such a special beer.

Comment: Agree with all of this, and a fourth reason would be the time it takes to brew (several months IIRC) tying up people and equipment.

Comment: You are right, I was going to edit my answer in order to expand point 1) to production costs (raw material + production time), but you arrived first.

Comment: By all means, still feel free to edit it into the answer!

Comment: #2 is wrong up to a point. In some states beer is beer and taxed the same no matter what and others when it goes above a certain ABV it kicks into another class of taxes.

Comment: #2 seems to depend on jurisdiction, unless you mean that Dogfish has to pay higher taxes where they produce it.  As for additions, please do [edit] to expand; we want the information to be in the post, not buried in comments.  Thanks.

Comment: It also has a higher rate of failure to brew (increasing cost). I watched a documentary (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brew_Masters) featuring the owner of Dogfish Head and sadly watched them dump a  whole fermenting tank because something when wrong and recall them discussing the high rate of failure and that is why they have a hard time making enough to keep it as a regularly stocked beer (I can't recall the last time I saw it even in specialty stores).

Comment: My guess is that 3) Marketing is the dominant reason. Make a special product, don't make much of it and price it high.